# Make CORS Middleware work for static files too in FastAPI

Tags: python, cors, fastapi, cross-origin-read-blocking

I have set CORS middleware in my FastAPI program.

```
origins = ["*"]

app.add_middleware(
  CORSMiddleware,
  allow_origins=origins,
  allow_credentials=True,
  allow_methods=["*"],
  allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

Everything works fine other than for static files am serving through /static/ mount.

```
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
```

How could I extend the CORS to this mount serving static files.

Answer (score 0):

*How could I extend the CORS to this mount serving static files.*

You already did.

In this line, you mount the `/static` route using `app` (which configured with `CORSMiddleware` middleware)

```
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
```

Comment: However for some reason the browser issues a CORS error (which vanished when i use a noCORS). Files delivered from the static mount does not contain the access-control-allow-credentials': 'true' header. :(

Comment: @BMC if you dont want CORS in the `/static` route, consider declare a separate `app` instance